# Map Win+M to an icon in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, icons, remapping

I would like to have an icon performing the function of the
<kbd>[image] (Win)</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> keyboard shortcut. Is this possible?

In other words, is it possible to change the "View desktop" icon so that it minimizes all windows (i.e., <kbd>[image] (Win)</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> functionality) instead of showing the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group1

There you will see the shortcut you are looking for.

Copy and paste on your desktop.